# Porquê que inner join retorna valores repetidos?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite,

Tenho um consulta a duas tabelas em que quero que da segunda tabela me retorne todos os dados com o id da tabela 1 mas só me retorna um valor da tabela quando existem mais que um com o mesmo id. Eu preciso que me retorne os dados todos da tabela estabelecimentos e que me retorne os dados que estão associados ao id do estabelecimento da tabela estabelecimentos.

**Código**

```
if($_REQUEST['valida'] != "ok"){
    if($result_alterar = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM estabelecimentos 
                                            INNER JOIN categorias_estabelecimentos ON categorias_estabelecimentos.estabelecimento_id = estabelecimentos.id
                                            WHERE estabelecimentos.id = :id ")){
        $result_alterar->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result_alterar->execute();
        if($result_alterar->rowCount() >0 ){
            $row_alterar = $result_alterar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $_REQUEST = $row_alterar; // O REQUEST ASSUME OS VALORES DO REGISTO, ASSIM EVITAMOS TER QUE CRIAR UM FORMULÁRIO INDEPENDENTE PARA AS EDIÇÕES

        }
    }
}
```

**Tabela categorias_estabelecimentos**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categorias_estabelecimentos` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`estabelecimento_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`categoria_slug` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=311 ;
```

**Tabela estabelecimentos**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `estabelecimentos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titulo` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `link_facebook` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `link_mapa` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `distritos` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `concelhos` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `morada` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `contacto` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `int_preco` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `link_site` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `introducao` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `servicos` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descricao` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `keywords_pesquisa` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `google_verification` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `activo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `pos` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=211 ;
```

**Var Dump da variável $_REQUEST**

http://pastebin.com/sJRswhvR

Comment: So o codigo nao da. Por favor poste a estrutura de cada tabela e seus respectivos conteudos. Tambem poste um `print_r()` e `array_dump` do $_REQUEST depois de defini-lo como $row_alterar

Comment: O que me acontece agora e que ele lista todos os dados respectivos da tabela categorias_estabelecimentos com o mesmo id da tabela estabelecimentos mas repete o conteudo vou por a estrutura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está pegando somente a primeira linha?

```
$row_alterar = $result_alterar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

O que ocorre se você mandar que ele retorne TODAS as linhas (Vai vir um Array no caso):

```
$row_alterar = $result_alterar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Isso faz retornar todos os valores, o problema é que talvez não resolva no seu uso (Pelo que entendi tem um formulário envolvido).

Nesse caso eu imagino que a solução seria mais na linha de atrelar um array com as categorias ao único estabelecimento. Correto?

Sugestão de código:

```
if($_REQUEST['valida'] != "ok"){
    if($result_alterar = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM estabelecimentos WHERE estabelecimentos.id = :id ")){
        $result_alterar->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result_alterar->execute();
        if($result_alterar->rowCount() >0 ){
            $row_alterar = $result_alterar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Puxamos as categorias relevantes para esse estabelecimento
            $result_categorias = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM categorias_estabelecimentos WHERE estabelecimento_id = :id ")
            $result_categorias->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result_categorias->execute();

            // Colocamos a listagem com as categorias como um elemento do estabelecimento
            // Esse é um exemplo que não foi testado, não manjo tanto do seu ORM.
            $row_alterar['categorias_estabelecimentos'] = $result_categorias->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Agora basicamente você tem um campo "categorias_estabelecimentos" que vai ter a listagem de categorias, em um único resultado com o estabelecimento que você precisa trabalhar.

            $_REQUEST = $row_alterar; // O REQUEST ASSUME OS VALORES DO REGISTO, ASSIM EVITAMOS TER QUE CRIAR UM FORMULÁRIO INDEPENDENTE PARA AS EDIÇÕES

        }
    }
}
```

Sugestão para imprimir checkboxes (Não completamente relacionado mas pode ser útil):

```
<?php foreach ($categorias_estabelecimentos as $cat) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="categorias_estabelecimentos[<?= $cat['id'] ?>]" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="categorias_estabelecimentos[<?= $cat['id'] ?>]" value="1" /> <?= $cat['categoria_slug'] ?>
<?php } ?>
```

O hidden é para, no post, ter a informação que algo foi desmarcado. É o padrão usado por frameworks como Rails e Angular. A sugestão é parcialmente não-relacionada mas considero relevante por tratar as peculiaridades de se lidar com arrays em telas de edição, o que é relevante à questão em pauta.

Comment: Sim isso tinha esquecido do fetchAll ja coloquei o problema e que agora retorna valores repetidos

Comment: Os valores da tabela estabelecimentos repete os mesmos dados o numero de dados que tem na tabela categorias

Comment: Atualizei com uma sugestão. Considerei o resultado como um array associativo, mas possivelmente ele é um objeto, e você talvez precise de algo tipo `$row_alterar->categorias_estabelecimentos` para funcionar.

Comment: Agora retorna bem mas nao assume o valor na varial request

Comment: César, coloca como você usa essa `$_REQUEST` depois para vermos como passar esses dados direitinho. :D

Comment: uso assim nos campos `<?= $_REQUEST['descricao'] ?>` por exemplo

Comment: César, nesse caso, `$_REQUEST['categorias_estabelecimentos']` vai ser um array, e você pode correr ele com algo como `<?php foreach ($categorias_estabelecimentos as $cat) { echo $cat['categoria_slug']; } ?>`

Comment: Lembrando que isso depende de $row_alterar poder receber esse novo valor. Em alguns frameworks como no Rails isso depende de uma configuração no Model.

Comment: nao uso frameworks e programado de raiz a unha

Comment: Dessa forma ja consigo chegar os dados do outro lado sem problemas agora estou com problema em checar os chekboxes

Comment: César, sugiro uma nova questão a respeito de checkboxes, os moderadores estão com cada vez mais "picuinhas". Coloque o link da nova questão aqui e eu te ajudo com o maior prazer. :D

Comment: Aqui fica o link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56404/problema-com-checkbox