# Problema com checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

Quando tento verificar pela base de dados se algum registo existe, marcar a checkbox como checada, sempre me retorna como não checado.

```
 <?php 

    $result_cat = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM colecoes WHERE activo = :activo");
    $result_cat->bindValue(':activo', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result_cat->execute();
    $row_cat_l = $result_cat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

     $qtd = count($_REQUEST['categorias_estabelecimentos']);

     for ( $i = 0; $i < $qtd ; $i++ ) {

        $cat = $_REQUEST['categorias_estabelecimentos'];

     }

    foreach ($row_cat_l as $row_cat) {

?>

        <label class='checkbox inline'>
            <input type="checkbox" <?=(in_array($row_cat->slug, $cat)?'checked="checked"':NULL)?> name="categoria[]" value="<? $row_cat->slug; ?>" />
            <?= $row_cat->titulo; ?>
        </label>


<?php 

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa de um array, mas está sobrescrevendo a variável `$cat` em vez de fazer ela ser um array de valores. Segue sugestão.

```
<?php 

    $result_cat = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM colecoes WHERE activo = :activo");
    $result_cat->bindValue(':activo', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result_cat->execute();
    $row_cat_l = $result_cat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

     $qtd = count($_REQUEST['categorias_estabelecimentos']);

     // PHP 5. Se o seu for mais antigo use $cat = array();
     $cat = [];

     for ( $i = 0; $i < $qtd ; $i++ ) {

        $cat[] = $_REQUEST['categorias_estabelecimentos'][$i]['slug'];

     }

    foreach ($row_cat_l as $row_cat) {

?>

        <label class='checkbox inline'>
            <input type="checkbox" <?=(in_array($row_cat->slug, $cat)?'checked="checked"':NULL)?> name="categoria[]" value="<? $row_cat->slug; ?>" />
            <?= $row_cat->titulo; ?>
        </label>


<?php 

    }

?>
```

Comment: Tentei mas continua sem marcar nenhuma

Comment: Já esta já funcionou nao tinha visto a sua alteração